# upgrading from Magento 1.3.2.4, database export/import issues

Tags: magento

Trying to upgrade from 1.3.2.4 to 1.4.

I set up MAMP and created an empty database into which I imported the exported database from the online site (done via phpMyAdmin from the cpanel of the site).

Copied 1.4 files into htdocs and got the installation screens.

After entering the details for the imported database, the process crashed and I got a blank screen.

I've tried changing the base url string in the core_config_data table and redone the whole process but to no avail.

I've also tried setting up a clean install of 1.4 and using the database repair tool to perhaps bring the old database up to spec but that didn't work either.

I basically need a proper way to upgrade this site to the latest version (1.8.1) but I thought I'd start with 1.4 first. At the very least I'd like to have a database that can work in a fresh 1.8.1 install.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what the error is before you can begin to fix it. The blank screen means that you are not getting those errors. It may be a simple timeout. What is in your php.ini for error reporting and timeouts?

With your 'MAMP' you can try a vanilla Magento install and see if that works. Try 1.3.2 with the demo data in the db first. Then point it at your copy of the live db and see if it still works or if it dies due to some module dependencies.

That should get you to the starting point. As for where you are now, check the apache log files to see if the error - maybe just a timeout - is in there.

On upgrade Magento does loads of stuff, as per the upgrade scripts with each module. This is database intensive stuff and by doing a dry run on a vanilla database you can see what you are up against.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've tried a vanilla install of 1.4.2 with an empty database and it seems to install properly (haven't tried with the demo data yet). The blank screen has this url, if it helps at all http://localhost:8888:8888/site-url/errors/report.php?id=953191019580&skin;=default.
So what you're suggesting is i install a vanilla 1.3.2 and after it's done installing, change the parameters so it's looking at the imported copy of the live db?